# Recover Windows Server instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

For some reason one my instances has become problematic. The error is:

> Instance reachability check failed

I've tried rebooting and stopping and starting. Neither of these operations worked. I figured it might be some sort of network issue and decided to create a new AMI from the faulty instance. I then launched the instance but it appears to have exactly the same problem as the original instance (I guess I cloned the problem too?).

Anyhow.... now I'm basically stumped. I'm guessing my only option is to create a brand new instance from a fresh image, mount the old hard-drive and copy things across. The amount of sysadmin I'd have to re-do though scares the crap out of me.

Do I have any other options available to me?

Comment: Contact Amazon support - you're paying way too much for just a Windows VM if you're not using their support.

Comment: Their direct support costs extra. I've posted to their forums so I'm just hedging my bets here. This little one is a micro instance so its not that pricey. Where else would you suggest I go by the way? I kinda suck at sysadmin.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a windows server error, sounds like an error with your vm. Have you [googled](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html)?

Comment: This error means that your VM is unreachable so it didn't boot correctly. It might be BSOD'ing but you can't see it. Have you tried the console yet?

Comment: @MDMoore313, aye, I've expired that list. The rest of it is only for Linux boxes.

Comment: @NathanC console is just pitch blackness. D:

Comment: Additionally I've tried creating images from the existing one. They also fail in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

There was no resolution in this particular instance.

Troubleshooting options mainly revolve around connecting the problematic volume to a different instance and examining the log files in drive:\windows\system32\winevt\logs.

We found nothing problematic in these logs suggesting the machine was unable to boot into windows to report the problem. My suspicion is that my machine in question has a faulty boot sector following a windows update as its the only explanation that makes sense.

I've had to rebuild the server from an older image D:.